# One Hot Encoding in Loss Function

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensor

I am trying to one hot encode predictions in my loss function.

```
def loss(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1e-7):
    y_true = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_true = one_hot(y_true, n_classes)
    y_pred = softargmax(y_pred)
    y_pred = K.flatten(y_pred)
    y_pred = one_hot(y_pred, n_classes)
    
    intersect = K.sum(y_true * y_pred, axis=-1)
    denom = K.sum(y_true + y_pred, axis=-1)
    return K.mean((2. * intersect / (denom + smooth)))
```

But casting `y_pred` to `int32` in order to use built in `K.one_hot` resuls in

```
 ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:
```

error. So I wrote my own one_hot encoding method that avoids casting `y_pred` to `int32`

```
def one_hot(xs, n_classes):
    table = tf.eye(n_classes, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
    return tf.map_fn(lambda x: table[tf.raw_ops.Cast(x=x, DstT=tf.int32)], xs)

one_hot(tf.constant([0.0, 1.0, 2.0]), 3)
```

My problems are as follows. Using `tf.gather/gatner_nd` results in the same gradient error the only function I can find that works without causing gradients error is `tf.map_fn` which is extremly slow switching to `vectorized_map` again results in gradient error. Is there another way to one hot encode that has gradients?

Comment: Why not just use [`tf.one_hot()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot)?

Comment: @gobrewers14 as i wrote in the question for one_hot to work y_pred must be cast to int32 operation does not have a gradient so does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a numerically stable version of `one_hot` by setting the biggest logit to 1.0 and masking.

```
import tensorflow as tf


def stable_one_hot(vec):
    """
    Args:
        vec: tf.Tensor, a batch of logits to be encoded
    
    Returns:
        tf.Tensor, a batch of numerically stable one-hot encoded logits
    """
    m = tf.math.reduce_max(vec, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    e = tf.math.exp(vec - m)
    mask = tf.cast(tf.math.not_equal(e, 1.0), tf.float32)
    vec -= 1e9 * mask
    return tf.nn.softmax(vec, axis=1)

# dummy data w/batch of size 32
X = tf.random.normal([32, 100])

# dummy labels w/10 possibilities
y = tf.random.uniform(shape=[32], minval=0, maxval=10, dtype=tf.int32)
# one-hot them
y_true = tf.one_hot(y, 10)

# simple network
nn = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)

# forward pass
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y_pred = nn(X)
    y_pred = stable_one_hot(y_pred)
    intersect = tf.math.reduce_sum(y_true * y_pred, -1)
    denom = tf.math.reduce_sum(y_true + y_pred, -1)
    loss = 2.0 * intersect / (denom + 1e-7)
    loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(loss)

grads = tape.gradient(loss, nn.trainable_variables)
assert grads != [None, None]

print(f"loss: {loss.numpy():.4f}")
# loss: 0.1250
```